# 401 Unauthorized API

Tags: javascript, fetch-api, http-status-code-401, weather, unauthorized

I've stumbled upon a problem whilst working on a weather app. I have 401 error popping up every time i'm trying to fetch API from openweathermap.com. I've tried everything so far to fix this problem like waiting some days until my API key would work for me. I also tried to create a new API key and use it but failed at it again. Finally i tried to create another account on openweathermap.com but still have this error. Can anyone help me to find out what is the problem?

P.S. i used a valid API for checking a basic weather info that is available for free subscribtion.

[401 Error screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hMcnY.png)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.  Please include your code and error as text and not as an image.  Please also make sure all code you post do not have any personal credentials.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)

Answer (score 0):

Your API Key is provided as a value to query parameter: `appid` is wrapped in `{}`. Remove those braces and perform the request again.

[image: Refering to the provided image]

Very often, you will find the usage of `{}` in the documents, they represent placeholders in a string and are not meant to be part of the final string.

- [Weathermap Docs: How to make an API Call?](https://openweathermap.org/api/one-call-3)

Also, please, make sure that you DO NOT share any essential API Keys in a public forum.

Answer (score 0):

{} should be removed inside the url. It should be

```
let api = `https://api/openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=${city}&appid=e2850163218373000f889c28107ac0cf`
```